# How can I get the glyph that was set manually for a given character?

Tags: c++, unicode, adobe-indesign

I can use the [Glyphs panel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS937002FB-8AC0-4520-AC7D-49C64A58EDB2a.html) to use a character with a manually chosen alternative glyph. But how can I then retrieve that glyph ID programmatically?

[image: Example of picking an alternate glyph]

I am currently using `IDrawingStyle::GetSpecialGlyph`, but it only works if the underlying character does not have a Unicode representation. But, say, if I drop some alternate glyph for the character U+0041 ʟᴀᴛɪɴ ᴄᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴀ in a document using the Glyphs panel, the underlying character will be U+0041, so `IDrawingStyle::GetSpecialGlyph` will not work. How can I programmatically retrieve that glyph ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this by navigating the wax. Iterate the wax strand with `CallbackWaxIterator`, and then, for each wax run boss on a wax line, obtain the `IWaxGlyphs` interface and use `PeekGlyphArray` or `MapCharsToGlyphs` in combination with `GetGlyphAt`.

Comment: I'm so glad you (a) found it (b) the time to post the answer (c) presumably understand what "for each _wax run boss_ on a _wax line_" means :)